# Jquery inArray not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Firebug when I rollover the SelectList variable it certainly looks like an array.

```
if (GroupList != "") {
    $('select[name^=DDLColumns1] option').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() != "-1") {
            var ItemsArray = $(this).val().split('|');
            var DataTypes = ItemsArray[1];
            var TestItem = "[" + ItemsArray[0] + "]";

PROBLEM IS HERE---> if (jQuery.inArray(TestItem, SelectList) != -1) {
                    if(DataTypes == 104)
                        NewSelectList += " SUM(CAST(" + ItemsArray[0] + " AS INT)) as " + ItemsArray[0] + ",";
                else
                    NewSelectList += " max(" + ItemsArray[0] + ") as " + ItemsArray[0] + ",";
            }

        }
    });
if(NewSelectList.length > 0) {
        NewSelectList = NewSelectList.substring(0, NewSelectList.length - 1);
        SelectList = NewSelectList;
    }

}//end of if GroupList is not empty
```

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, if (jQuery.inArray(ItemsArray[0], SelectList) != -1) {

Comment: Your code is a mess... gonna clean it up...

Comment: is anybody going to answer the actual question???

Comment: Its not my fault the indentation on this forum isn't the same as my indentation which makes it look messy

Comment: SelectList contains "[DateDue],[TypeFileID],... etc.. so I need to format the TestItem variable to match the values in the SelectList.

Comment: when does this code get executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if($.isArray( SelectList ) == false)
    SelectList = SelectList.split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

What about cleaning up that mess first? Your errors should get clear if you do it.

```
if (GroupList != "") {
    $('select[name^=DDLColumns1] option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "-1") {
            var ItemsArray = $(this).val().split('|');
            var DataTypes = ItemsArray[1];
            var TestItem = "[" + ItemsArray[0] + "]";

            if (jQuery.inArray(TestItem, SelectList) != -1) {
                if(DataTypes == 104)
                    NewSelectList += " SUM(CAST(" + ItemsArray[0] + " AS INT)) as " + ItemsArray[0] + ",";

                else // <--- why all of a sudden no {}?

                    NewSelectList += " max(" + ItemsArray[0] + ") as " + ItemsArray[0] + ",";
            }
            //} //<--- why is commented out? it breaks everything

        } //<-- this closes the callback

}); //<-- broken close of the if

if(NewSelectList.length > 0) {
    NewSelectList = NewSelectList.substring(0, NewSelectList.length - 1);
    SelectList = NewSelectList;
}



} // <---- what is this for? yeah it's broken
```

PS: Normally variables start with a lowercase letter and classes start with an uppercase one

Comment: Please look again, I see 5 {'s and 5 }'s

Comment: @Lyle That doesn't make it any good, the order of the closing `}` is still broken.

Comment: Why no { s? because the if and else statement only execute one statement.

Comment: I'm sorry but squabbling over the syntax doesn't help me, I know it executes fine or Firebug wouldn't be stepping down into it, I cut out some commented out experiments, the real problem is in the one inArray statement.

Comment: @Lyle unless you show us some actual working code, we can only make guesses about what you code looks like, care to edit your answer?

Comment: @Lyle ...goosh.. but now for us... we can only guess. Also what's the content of `ItemsArray`? You want to format it the same way to make it match, so we need to know how the stuff in there looks.

Comment: ItemsArray contains the name of the selected column, this is a dynamically populated array from a sql statement that is passed through ajax ItemsArray contains two values: "ColumnName|ColumnDataType" Dont ask to see the entire Jquery script because it is more than 800 lines of code now..

Comment: My only conclusion is that somehow even though the SelectList is populated and looks like an array Jquery doesn't evaluate it as an array for the purpose of the inArray function?? Is there a way I can make sure the type is array prior to attempting the inArray function?